# JavaFX create and use custom control with it's own functions

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a simple custom control as shown in picture:
[image]

when I click on "Click me" button the console shows me this message "The button was clicked!" by a function called `doSomething`, and this is the custom control's fxml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<fx:root prefHeight="83.0" prefWidth="196.0" type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="196.0" />
      <Button layoutX="72.0" layoutY="29.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSomething" text="Click me" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

And this is the controller of this custom control:

```
package control;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller extends AnchorPane {
    @FXML private TextField textField;

    public Controller() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomControlView.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        textProperty().set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return textField.textProperty();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
    }
}
```

The control is working good and I can call it in another fxml file using "JavaFX scence builder" (as shown in picture) :
[image]

And this is the fxml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="324.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane layoutX="64.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="196.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="196.0" />
            <Button layoutX="72.0" layoutY="29.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSomething" text="Click me" />
         </children>
      </javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="75.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Trying the custom control:">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

But the problem is that I have to redefine the `doSomething` function of the custom control button !!!I mean when I added my custom conrol to another fxml file all the functions of this custom control should work without redefining it just like `Swing`.
Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Scene Builder just copies the code of your custom control into the new control rather than linking it. To use your custom control you have to use the `fx:include` FXML tag.

So the FXML file should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="324.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <fx:include source="yourCustomControl.fxml" />
      <Label layoutX="75.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Trying the custom control:">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

However, you have to do this manually. As far as I know, the Scene Builder is not capable of doing it.